# SSRS Reports from Azure Table Storage - possible?

Tags: azure

Greetings,

Is it possible to render SSRS Reports with **Table Storage** data source? if yes, if you could guide me the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. Actually, table storage doesn't support even aggregate functions.

Comment: How about SSIS ETL, possible?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not look into azure table storage.  However, because RDLC-based reports can use objects as the data source, you could bind your rdlc reports to ATS (which still get you reporting capabilities, but without server-side features)